# Convert the string into a float value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have copied a  table with three columns from a pdf file. I am attaching the screenshot from the PDF here:

[image]

The values in the column **padj** are exponential values, however, when you copy from the pdf to an excel and then open it with pandas, these are strings or object data types. Hence, these values cannot be parsed as floats or numeric values. I need these values as floats, not as strings. Can someone help me with some suggestions?
So far this is what I have tried.

The excel or the `csv` file is then opened in python using the `escape_unicode` encoding in order to circumvent the **UnicodeDecodeError**

```
## open the file
df       = pd.read_csv("S2_GSE184956.csv",header=0,sep=',',encoding='unicode_escape')[["DEGs","LFC","padj"]]

   df.head()
        DEGs   padj          LFC
    0   JUNB    1.5 ×10-8   -1.273329
    1   HOOK2   2.39×10-7   -1.109320
    2   EGR1    3.17×10-6   -4.187828
    3   DUSP1   3.95×10-6   -3.251030
    4   IL6     3.95×10-6   -3.415500
    5   ARL4C   5.06×10-6   -2.147519
    6   NR4A2   2.94×10-4   -3.001167
    7   CCL3L1  4.026×10-4  -5.293694


# Convert the string to float by replacing the x10- with exponential sign 
    df['padj'] = df['padj'].apply(lambda x: (unidecode(x).replace('x10-','x10-e'))).astype(float)
That threw an error,

    ValueError: could not convert string to float: '1.5 x10-e8'
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the dataframe shared in the question on [this last edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74205860/revisions), the following using [`pandas.Series.str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) and [`pandas.Series.astype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.astype.html) will do the work:

```
df['padj'] = df['padj'].str.replace('×10','e').str.replace(' ', '').astype(float)
```

The goal is to get the cells to look like the following `1.560000e-08`.

---

**Notes:**

- Depending on the rest of the dataframe, additional adjustments might still be required, such as, removing the spaces `'` that might exist in one of the cells. For that one can use [`pandas.Series.str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) as follows

  ```
  df['padj'] = df['padj'].str.replace("'", '')
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Considering your sample (column padj), the code below should work:

```
f_value = eval(str_float.replace('x10', 'e').replace(' ', ''))
```

Answer (score 1):

Updated based on the data you provided above. The most significant thing being that the x is actually a times symbol:

```py
import pandas as pd
DEGs = ["JUNB", "HOOK2", "EGR1", "DUSP1", "IL6", "ARL4C", "NR4A2", "CCL3L1"]
padj = ["1.5 ×10-8", "2.39×10-7", "3.17×10-6", "3.95×10-6", "3.95×10-6", "5.06×10-6", "2.94×10-4", "4.026×10-4"]
LFC = ["-1.273329", "-1.109320", "-4.187828", "-3.251030", "-3.415500", "-2.147519", "-3.001167", "-5.293694"]
df = pd.DataFrame({'DEGs': DEGs, 'padj': padj, 'LFC': LFC})
# change to python-friendly float format
df['padj'] = df['padj'].str.replace(' ×10-', 'e-', regex=False)
df['padj'] = df['padj'].str.replace('×10-', 'e-', regex=False)
# convert padj from string to float
df['padj'] = df['padj'].astype(float)
```

will give you this dataframe:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you want a numerical vectorial solution, you can use:

```
df['float'] = (df['padj'].str.extract(r'(\d+(?:\.\d+))\s*×10(.?\d+)')
 .apply(pd.to_numeric).pipe(lambda d: d[0].mul(10.**d[1]))
)
```

output:

```
     DEGs        padj       LFC         float
0    JUNB   1.5 ×10-8 -1.273329  1.500000e-08
1   HOOK2   2.39×10-7 -1.109320  2.390000e-07
2    EGR1   3.17×10-6 -4.187828  3.170000e-06
3   DUSP1   3.95×10-6 -3.251030  3.950000e-06
4     IL6   3.95×10-6 -3.415500  3.950000e-06
5   ARL4C   5.06×10-6 -2.147519  5.060000e-06
6   NR4A2   2.94×10-4 -3.001167  2.940000e-04
7  CCL3L1  4.026×10-4 -5.293694  4.026000e-04
```

Intermediate:

```
df['padj'].str.extract('(\d+(?:\.\d+))\s*×10(.?\d+)')

       0   1
0    1.5  -8
1   2.39  -7
2   3.17  -6
3   3.95  -6
4   3.95  -6
5   5.06  -6
6   2.94  -4
7  4.026  -4
```

Comment: I am not looking for a numerical vectorial format. I need the value to be in float or exponential format. Thanks for the answer! I appreciate

Comment: @user1017373 isn't it what my solution does? see column "float" in the output